# Problems with Cisco VPN client installation for Archos 5 IT

Tags: android, kernel-module, archos

I have an Archos 5 IT firmware v2.0.38 with Android 1.6 and I did not find any site how to install vpnc. The main problem is that I do not know how to compile/crosscompile the tun.ko module and the vpnc package. I do have root access on the device.

Comment: Is VPNC a "standard" Linux app?  If so, I highly doubt it will work on Android.  Android uses a Linux kernel but it is a very different OS.

Comment: It is working on Android. See: http://code.google.com/p/get-a-robot-vpnc/

Comment: The app is in the Market and also available for download, according to that link.  You don't need to compile it yourself.

Comment: The problem is that tun driver is specific to the kernel and architecture.

Comment: OK, understood.  In that case, I think you need development-level help and not user-level help.  You can get the former on StackOverflow.com, I'll flag for the mods to move it there.

Comment: have you considered trying to use one of the ROMs that they recommend on the project page? (i.e. CyanoGen, JesusFreke). If a different ROM is not an option for you, then you will need to get an android build environment and try to build the module yourself. This is likely to be pretty complicated - try [this search](http://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+build+tun.ko+for+android&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t)

Comment: I will check if it is possible to install CyanoGen on Archos5IT.

Comment: No, it is not supported. I will try to compile it.